# How to show different content depending on UserGroup in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have created a `password_change_done` template.

But I need to to show a `Back to Dashboard` button for Employees and a `Back to Profile` for Customers.

How can I achieve this through UserGroup checking, without messing with the `views.py`?

Comment: it mean you have to render your customize template of  `password_change_done` ?

Comment: I only want to change the `Back to (...)` button based on the group the user is in.

Comment: How you are differenciate that user group is `employee` or `customer` ?

Comment: Through Django groups. I have a `Clients` group and a `Employees` group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have to use the `filter` of the template as below...

In your app create a folder 'templatetags'. In this folder create two files:

1. __init__.py
2. get_group.py

The folder structure looks like ...

```
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        get_group.py
    views.py
```

**get_group.py file :**

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name): 
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

Then in your html page use it as below...

```
{% load get_group %}

{% if request.user|has_group:"Client" %} 
    ... Back to Dashboard button ...
{% else %}
    ... Back to profile button ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Great, Happy Coding :)